# Merge Duplicate Rows with different Values in one Row using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, merge, attribute-joins

I joined a table with the area of a value to a shapefile with building footprints. Now I have up to 3 rows with the same ObjectId/Single Building Footprint (from the Join) but each of the 3 rows has its corresponding areas and values.

What I want is just Single Building Footprints/Polygons with the 3 different area values in one row, as different fields.

Would a tool like [Concatenate Row Values](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/concatenate-row-values/#:%7E:text=Concatenating%20row%20values&text=This%20tool%20is%20based%20on,but%20updates%20the%20input%20data.) do it?

Comment: Have you tried using the Dissolve tool?

Comment: Yes I did. It doesn't give the results I wanted. I just splitted the Table I joined to my feature layer in 3 parts, with the corresponding rows and now i just joined them seperatly to the feature layer.
I think this solved the problem, but If anyone knows a more inteligent or better workflow for this I'm happy to hear it. Always good to learn new tools an workflows.

Comment: But now because of the Join to the feature layer the performance is really bad. Still open for some solution.

Comment: I think you should use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with more details of what your input and output feature attributes should look like.